HTML to MS Word (Header and Footer disappeared)
I have a pcf component that creates a word docx file after the response of a powerautomate flow that generates an HTML.
HTML is like this:
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<style>
@page
{
    mso-page-orientation: landscape;
    size:29.7cm 21cm;    margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;
}
@page Section1 {
    mso-header-margin:.5in;
    mso-footer-margin:.5in;
    mso-header: h1;
    mso-footer: f1;
    }
div.Section1 { page:Section1; }
table#hrdftrtbl
{
    margin:0in 0in 0in 900in;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter
{
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
    font-size:12.0pt;
}
</style>
<xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>
<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml>
</head>

<body>
<div class="Section1">

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<br/>
    <table id='hrdftrtbl' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr><td>        <div style='mso-element:header' id=h1 >
        <!-- HEADER-tags -->
            <p class=MsoHeader >HEADER</p>
        <!-- end HEADER-tags -->
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div style='mso-element:footer' id=f1><span style='position:relative;z-index:-1'> 
        <!-- FOOTER-tags -->
        FOOTER

        <span style='mso-no-proof:yes'><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shapetype
         id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t"
         path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
         <v:formulas>
          <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
         </v:formulas>
         <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
         <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
        </v:shapetype><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_1" o:spid="_x0000_s3073" type="#_x0000_t75"
         alt="VHB" style='position:absolute;
         margin-right:0pt;margin-top:-400pt;
         z-index:-1;
         visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;
         mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;
         mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;
         mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;
         mso-position-vertical-relative:text'>
         <v:imagedata src="https://www.google.bg/logos/2012/Rodin-2012-homepage.png"/>
        </v:shape><![endif]--></span>
           <p class=MsoFooter>
           <span style='mso-tab-count:2'></span>
           Page <span style='mso-field-code: PAGE'><span style='mso-no-proof:yes'></span> from <span style='mso-field-code: NUMPAGES'></span>

        <!-- end FOOTER-tags -->
   </span>


        </p>
    </div>



    <div style='mso-element:header' id='fh1'>
        <p class='MsoHeader'><span lang='EN-US' style='mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
        </div>
        <div style='mso-element:footer' id='ff1'>
        <p class='MsoFooter'><span lang='EN-US' style='mso-ansi-language:EN-US'>&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span></p>
    </div>

    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body></html>

The file is generated correctly, but there is a problem. After opening and editing the file in online mode or from the word app, I close the file and reopen but the header and footer disappear. Can you help me?

I don't think putting the header, body and footer in a single table is going to work - yes, it looks alright when you open the document. Here, if I change it, save it as .docx, and re-open it, most of it has "gone", and although it re-appears if I select View->Read Mode, Word clearly does not really "like" it and I don' think you will be able to get it to work reliably. AFAICS in order to save a header when saving to HTML, you either have to use multi-file HTML (where the header is in a separate file, or in MHTML format, which is probably not easy to create programmatically...

...so if you do not actually have to use HTML but need a format you can generate, perhaps use another format such as single-file .xml (@either the Word 2003 version or the later "FlatOPC"
